# How to put a varrient inside an array in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get data from mysql and try to put it in array loop.

that is what I want to reach my aim;

```
<?php
$carsa = '"Volvo","Deneme"';
$cars = array($carsa);
echo $cars[0];
?>
```

in that I get **"Volvo","Deneme"**

But I need to get **Volvo**

Where is my mistake.
Thanks

Comment: Explode it dear liza, dear lisa ['explode()'](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it

Comment: That is not [an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: How is MySQL related? Please share more code, likely `$carsa` creation is incorrect, or MySQL return is incorrect.

Comment: _"Where is my mistake"_ - you are not making the proper distinction between _code_, and _data_. Just because you put something into string variable that _looks_ like PHP syntax, doesn't mean it will get _interpreted_ as PHP. Your code is pretty much the same, as if you had written `$cars = array('"Volvo","Deneme"');` directly - and _of course_ that creates an array with _one_ item only, because that _is_ only one value.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Oh damn I got that!  Now the damn hole in the bucket is running through my head...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use explode which will convert to array:

```
 $carsa = '"Volvo","Deneme"';
 $cars = explode(",",$carsa);
 echo trim($cars[0],'"');
```